# Can't Find Documentation For wp_styles in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm seeing references to properties on global variables that I can't seem to find any documentation for in WordPress.  For instance `$wp_styles->queue` and `$wp_styles->registered` , see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35239313/1733651) which contains similar code to the below:

```
function inspect_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    print_r($wp_scripts->queue);
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'inspect_scripts' );

function inspect_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    print_r($wp_styles->queue);
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'inspect_styles' );
```

However when I try to find documentation for these properties in the codex for [WP_Styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_styles/) there is no mention of those properties.  I also don't see a mention of these globals on the [WordPress globals](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) page.  Where are people getting the information they need to write/use this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP_Styles extends WP_Dependencies, and WP_Dependencies is where you find ->queue, ->registered, etc.